# How to create native class using JNI?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I want to create C++ class with constructor and one method which returns string. My question is: how to initialize object of type "native class" in Java using C++ constructor and then from this Java object call native method?

Comment: Just to be clear: Native = C, not C++. You cannot use C++ with JNI unless you create an interface that binds C with Java, and then instantiate C++ classes inside C, where the latter is compiled with a C++ compiler, since C++ compilers understand C.

Comment: Plese go through link link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk. I believe it will help you.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Thanks, got it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist That is completely incorrect. You can use C++ as long as the native JNI methods observe the signatures generated by `javah`. I was doing this twenty years ago.

Comment: @EJP What does "observe the signatures generated by `javah`" mean? You're telling me that ,e.g., you can use JNI to call a method takes `std::shared_ptr` as argument and returns `std::string`?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Yes. I've done it. That's why `javah` generates `extern "C"` statements.

Comment: @EJP So If I have a function that takes `std::shared_ptr` as argument and returns `std::string`, `javah` will automatically create/generate a C interface that's compatible with that method?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist No, it will create a C interface that is compatible with the Java native method in the class it was told to generate a C header for. It can't see your C++ method, but it can see the Java native method. You need to do further study on this, and specifically on the `javah` tool. This is rather basic.

Comment: @EJP Actually we don't disagree, but you misunderstood what I said.

Comment: @EJP That's your opinion. You're apparently a Java dev and are not familiar with C++ ABI problems. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It's not my 'opinion'. It is designed-in and established fact. The native method itself can be written in any language whatsoever that satisfies the C linkage generated by `javah`. Your guesswork about what I am and am not familiar with is both inaccurate and irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it's your opinion. If `javah` generates a native interface, that doesn't mean that a C++ ABI can directly interface with JNI. NATIVE = C. No matter how much you jump around this fact, it'll remain true. Otherwise tools like SWIG would've been useless. You obviously don't understand what I'm talking about, and are driven by your experience, not the will to learn or understand your peers. I seriously don't have time for your judgmental attitude.

Comment: I am sorry that my question created such argue, I just wanted to have answer to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'native class' in Java; we have 'native methods' that can be part of any Java class. The native methods are implemented as `extern "C"` functions.

In the nutshell, you can create in your Java two native methods, e.g. `createNativeInstance` and `getNativeString`. Note that you probably need another method to release the native instance:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT
jlong Java_test_createNativeInstance(JNIEnv *, jobject ) {
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(new CppClass());
}

JNIEXPORT
jstring Java_test_getNativeString(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong cppClassPtr) {
    CppClass* pCppClass = reinterpret_cast<CppClass*>(cppClassPtr);
    return env->NewStringUTF(env, pCppClass->getString();
}

JNIEXPORT
void Java_test_releaseNativeInstance(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong cppClassPtr) {
    CppClass* pCppClass = reinterpret_cast<CppClass*>(cppClassPtr);
    delete pCppClass;
}
```

The Java file **test.java** may look like:

```
public class test {
    public native long createNativeInstance();
    public native String getNativeString(long cppClassPtr);
    public native void releaseNativeInstance(long cppClassPtr);
}
```

Comment: This is extremely interesting.  How is this actually knit together into a class?  I.e. something that you could call `GetMethodID` on?  It looks like this is C code that is emulating a class.  I just can't figure out the rest of the code, i.e. how `Java_test_getNativeString` is used.

Comment: `Java_test_getNativeString` is an implementation of the method `native string getNativeString(long cppClassPtr)` of Java class `test`.

Comment: What would the Java side look like?  Is there any way of defining the java class without any Java code?

Comment: Yes, you can: see the edited post

Comment: Ah, but we still need to define the class somehow? I was wondering if there was a way of doing it procedurally.  Native activities are really painful to touch anything java-wise in.  No `DefineClass` or anything else like it.  I will play with this, though.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to define Java classes on the fly on Android.